# CosmosDB query on date range + index

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a cosmos DB whose size is around 100GB. 
I successfully create a nice partition key, i have around 4600 partition on 70M records, but I still need to query on two datetime fields that are stored as a string, not in an epoch format.

Example json:

```
"someField1": "UNKNOWN",
"someField2": "DATA",
"endDate": 7014541201,
"startDate": 7054864502,
"someField3": "0",
"someField3": "0",
```

i notice when i do `select * from tbl`  and when i do `select * from tbl where startDate > {someDate} AND endDate<{someDate1}` latency different is around 1s, so this filtering does not decrease my latency time. 
Is it better to store date types as number? Does cosmos have better performance on epoch query ranges? 
I am using SQL API.

Also when i try to add hash indexes on a startDate and endDate he basically convert that into two indexes. 
Example:

```
 "path": "/startDate/?",
        "indexes": [
            {
                "kind": "Hash",
                "dataType": "String",
                "precision": 3
            }
            ]
    },
```

this is converted to

```
"path": "/startDate/?",
        "indexes": [
            {
                "kind": "Range",
                "dataType": "Number",
                "precision": -1
            },
            {
                "kind": "Range",
                "dataType": "String",
                "precision": -1
            }
        ]
```

Is that a normal behaviour or it is related to my data? 
Thanks.

I checked query metrics, and for 4k records query to cosmosDB is executed in 100ms. I would like to ask you is it normal behaviour that

```
var option = new FeedOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey),  MaxItemCount = -1};

var query= client.CreateDocumentQuery<MyModel>(collectionLink, option)
            .Where(tl => tl.StartDate >= DateTimeToUnixTimestamp(startDate) && tl.EndDate <= DateTimeToUnixTimestamp(endDate))
        .AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

this query returns 10k results (in Postman its around 9MB size) in 10-12s? This partition contains around 50k records.

> Retrieved Document Count            :          12,356
>   Retrieved Document Size                  :      12,963,709 bytes
>   Output Document Count                    :           3,633
>   Output Document Size                     :       3,819,608 bytes
>   Index Utilization                        :           29.00 %
>   Total Query Execution Time               :          264.31
>   milliseconds
>
> > Query Compilation Time                 :            0.12 milliseconds
> >
> > Logical Plan Build Time              :            0.07 milliseconds
> >
> > Physical Plan Build Time             :            0.06 milliseconds
> >
> > Query Optimization Time              :            0.01 milliseconds
> >
> > Index Lookup Time                      :           51.10 milliseconds
> >
> > Document Load Time                     :          140.51 milliseconds
> >
> > Runtime Execution Times
> >
> > Query Engine Times                   :           55.61 milliseconds
> >
> > System Function Execution Time       :            0.00 milliseconds
> >
> > User-defined Function Execution Time :            0.00 milliseconds
> >
> > Document Write Time                    :           10.56 milliseconds
> >
> > Client Side Metrics
>
> Retry Count                            :           0
>
> > ```
> >         Request Charge                         :          904.73 RUs
> > ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am from the CosmosDB engineering team.

Since your collection has 70M records, I assume that the observed latency is only on the first roundtrip (or first page) of results. Note that the observed latency can also be improved by tweaking FeedOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism to -1 when executing the query.

Regarding the difference between the two queries themselves, please note that SELECT * without a filter is a full scan query, which is probably a bit 
faster to first return results, when compared to the other query with two filters, which does a little bit more work on the local indexes across all the partitions, which may explain the observed latency.

Regarding your other question, we no longer support the Hash indexing policy on new collections. Please see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-types#index-kind . We automatically convert Hash indexes to Range with full precision.

You may also fetch QueryMetrics for your query and analyze the results to figure out why you have latency. Details are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-query-metrics#query-execution-metrics

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I set MaxDegree from the beginning, and I also increased throughput but I am not getting the performance that I was hoping to get. 
I will play with QueryMetrics to analyze my requests, maybe I will get back to you here. 
Much appreciated.

Comment: i edited my question, adding some query metrics result and c# code that is called. 
Hope that this can give you more input.

Comment: Please post query metrics output as well (the string representation of the query metrics dictionary that you get in the response) so I can take a look

Comment: Hi Krishnan, i updated my question. Hope this gives more insights

Comment: I also now excluded unnecessary paths, i got index utilization 100%, also i changed the code to query AsDocument(), for better performance. 
Are there more tips that I can upgrade my code for better response time?

Comment: It is surprising to me that excluding unnecessary paths boosted index utilization to 100%. Did you add some paths previously not present in your indexing policy?

Comment: no, I just excluded ones that I do not use in my query.

Comment: i will give it a shot with new 3.0 SDK :) 

Well I see index utilization as now the index database is smaller, so scan time is lower too ( i don't know why I see it like this, it was a desperate try :) )

I optimized the query and document size, and now for the response of 7MB I got response time around 4500ms. I still think it can be better with a new feature on 3.0 to take raw results as it is possible with js

Comment: Hey, I am from the Cosmos DB engineering team. Please drop me a note at krishs at microsoft dot com when possible. I want to explore this further if that's OK with you.

Comment: i dropped you an email yesterday. 
Let me know if you received it.

Comment: Hey guys, not sure if there has been any progress since this has been documented but would be greatly appreciated if there is more information on this